# Maven: download all the artifacts of a group

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus

I am using maven 3.0 with nexus as remote repository. 
I am wondering, is there a way to download all the artifacts with the same groupId using maven without knowing the name of all the artifacts? In other words, is it possible to download all the artifacts from remote repository automatically by only mentioning the group Id?

For example, I want to download all the artifacts in group com.example.here to my local repository:

```
<groupId>com.example.here</groupId>
```

artifacts:

```
<artifactId>a1</artifactId>
...
<artifactId>an</artifactId>
```

and the version that I want is the latest.

Comment: There had been a discussion about on the Mailing list about a kind of boot-strap for Maven but the question is why do you need it in this particular case? Which use-case do you have?

Comment: I have different projects with the same groupId which will be put on the same server. I thought instead of copying all the ear files into the server, simply just download all the artifacts on the server with a simple script. But the number of artifacts might grow. so, I thought this way it would be scale-able.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru) (should be included in many UNIX distributions) to mirror a part of a Maven repository. Since the repository uses sub-directories based on groupIDs, you can use that do fetch all artifacts belonging to a certain group. E.g.

```
$ lftp https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/apache-xalan/ -e 'mirror .'
```

Will grab everything under the apache-xalan groupId.

*This may not work with every Maven repository. Some may only allow access to the directory structure at a certain depth or not at all.*

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do this since a dependency in maven needs to be referred by groupId:artifactId:version:classifier (optional).

One way I can think of is to create an assembly project that has dependencies on all the projects you want to download and the version optionally set to LATEST. You can use maven assembly plugin to create an archive from the dependency sets.